# Retrieve PC Model from BIOS information

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to update the BIOS on the PCs within my organization using the HP Bios Configuration Utility and I need a it to check a registry value in order to apply the appropriate configuration.

I found this code on the internet but can't get it to work:

```
@echo off
ECHO BIOS check HP
CD c:\Batch\bios\HP
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\Description\system\BIOS" /v "SystemProductName" | find /i "HP ProDesk 600 G3 PCI MT"
if errorlevel 0 (
    echo HP ProDesk 600 G3 PCI MT
 goto :end
)
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\Description\system\BIOS" /v "SystemProductName" | find /i "HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR"
if errorlevel 0 (
   echo HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR
 goto :end
)
:end
PAUSE
```

The error level doesn't work but it does look for the value.

This is what I'm using currently but `systeminfo` is taking too long to load on some PCs with a lot of hotfixes:

```
systeminfo > C:\Temp\Sysinf%t%.txt

CD c:\Batch\bios\HP

find "System Model:              HP ProDesk 600 G3 PCI MT" C:\Temp\Sysinf%t%.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :Leg_HP_ProDesk_600_G3_PCI_MT
find "System Manufacturer:       HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR" C:\Temp\Sysinf%t%.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :Leg_HP_EliteDesk_800_G1_TWR 

:Leg_HP_ProDesk_600_G3_PCI_MT
BiosConfigUtility64.exe /setconfig:Leg_HP_ProDesk_600_G3_PCI_MT.txt /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
goto :Setpass
:Leg_HP_EliteDesk_800_G1_TWR
BiosConfigUtility64.exe /setconfig:Leg_HP_EliteDesk_800_G1_TWR.txt /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
goto :Setpass


:Setpass
BIOSConfigUtility64.exe /nspwdfile:"newpassword.bin" /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
```

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` means "if errorlevel is zero or higher". Change to `if not errorlevel 1` (meaning "if errorlevel is not 1 or higher")

Comment: `wmic csproduct get name`

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this to work reasonably well, *as long as `BiosConfigUtility64.exe` the `.txt` and `.bin` files are in `C:\Batch\bios\HP`*:

```bat
@Set "SPN="&For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query ^
 "HKLM\Hardware\Description\system\BIOS" /V "SystemProductName" 2^>NUL^|^
 "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IC:"HP ProDesk 600 G3 PCI MT" /C:"HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR"^"'
)Do @Set "SPN=%%B"
@If Not Defined SPN Exit /B
@CD /D "C:\Batch\bios\HP" 2>NUL||Exit /B
@"BIOSConfigUtility64.exe" /SetConfig:"Leg_%SPN: =_%.txt" /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
@"BIOSConfigUtility64.exe" /nspwdfile:"newpassword.bin" /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
```

If you create all of your text files using the same naming format, *(the returned name with spaces replaced with underscores and prefixed with `Leg_`)*, you could forget about the using [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr), just save the value and then check for an existing, matching `.txt` file:

```bat
@CD /D "C:\Batch\bios\HP" 2>NUL||Exit /B
@For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query ^
 "HKLM\Hardware\Description\system\BIOS" /V "SystemProductName" 2^>NUL^"')Do @Set "SPN=%%B"
@If Not Exist "Leg_%SPN: =_%.txt" Exit /B
@"BIOSConfigUtility64.exe" /SetConfig:"Leg_%SPN: =_%.txt" /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
@"BIOSConfigUtility64.exe" /nspwdfile:"newpassword.bin" /cspwdfile:"currentpassword.bin"
```